# How to implement sms retrieve api in flutter

Tags: flutter, sms

I want my app to take OTP automatically, In android, we have the SMS retrieval API for that, so how to implement the same thing for IOS and android using flutter

Comment: I was looking for it via rest api without firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no official Flutter plugin developed by the Flutter team for this. You have two options for this:

1. Use plugins created by the developer community. Try [sms_retriever](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_retriever).
2. Write your own platform-specific code (e.g. your Android code in Java), and invoke it from Flutter. Read more about this [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).